# Cut-out effect using Image Mask not working for me

Tags: xcode, scenekit, wavefront, sceneeditor

I'm not able to resolve this issue in multiple plant models I got from Turbosquid.

Specifically, the Petals of the flowers like the one pictured here. Petals appear as rectangles (as per original Geometry) even with Transparency set to a masking image (attached). I've also attached a screenshot of settings as SceneKit Editor/XCode show. Any idea what am I missing?

[Rendered Object (Yellow Flowers with Rectangular Petals) with partial Material Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO2Zq.jpg)
[Additional Material Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHDBG.png)
[Masking Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHDLE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to set the transparency mode to "RBG Zero" in the UI (which maps to [`SCNTransparencyModeRGBZero`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransparencymode/scntransparencymodergbzero)).

Note that it'll require the image to be inverted (black is opaque, white is transparent).

Comment: Perfect! That worked like a charm, and I learnt something new. Thank you so much!